# Enable preset plugins in Ckeditor 4.5.8

Tags: plugins, ckeditor, laravel-5, cdn

I am using CKeditor via cdn `//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.8/full/ckeditor.js`.

I wish to enable a preset plugin and do not know how to go about it. i need clear code example.

I have seen this [tutorial on using the cdn](https://cdn.ckeditor.com/) but it talks about local plugins.

[Code snippet](http://ckeditor.com/addon/codesnippet) is one of the plugins I want to enable.

Working locally with CKeditor in laravel 5.2 is a lot of headache. I keep have this error `SyntaxError: illegal character` when I inmport my javascript files. My laravel view uses blade template engine. I do not have this issues with CDN imports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue after many days. all the javascript(not only Ckeditor or Tinymce) files I imported in laravel always gave the `syntaxError: illegal character` like this

[image]

I notices that in every response a header information was automatically pasted as well as a funny character. I solved this using two major steps.

1. I opened all the javascript files using notepad++ and deleted the first line (usually comments) using backspace and type it back manually, then saved the files.
2. I realized the header info `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` was some how related to the server configuration. I switched form using the in-built server `php artisan serve` to virtual host on xampp. And everything works well.

NB: This problem has nothing to do with Laravel 5.x. I personally think that this problems arise due to the copying and pasting, and downloading of files from the server.
To benefit from the advanced features of a full flesh server, I decided to use virtual host in xampp for development.

I am very happy. Hope it helps!